# Make $.ajax call to url without knowing dataType

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I'm trying to set up a generic call to webservices using jquery $.ajax. I'd like to be able to get raw data back and bind it to a grid.

I have calls working correctly when I know the dataType, but I want to try and make an ajax call without knowing the datatype, specifically to find what the dataType is.

For example, my ajax call knowing the datatype could be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=coldplay',
    success: function (res, status, xhr) {
        //DoStuff;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //DoStuff
    }
});
```

But any time I make a request without knowing the datatype I simply get a response status of "Error"?

What I would eventually like to be able to do with this is ping a url (webservice) that returns json, xml, or perhaps odata(unlikely). Since I won't know which, I want to be able to simply make a call to the url once to find out what kind of data I might get back, along with what content-type there is.

I've tried simply getting back the content type in the header in the error, but so far nothing I've tried has worked or returned anything at all.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=coldplay',
    success: function (res, status, xhr) {
        //DoStuff
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#results").html(textStatus + jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
    }
});
```

Can this even be done with Jquery?

**Edit**

I am aware that this can (and in most cases should) be done server side, and in all likelihood this is what will end up happening. But for the purposes of seeing how far I can go binding a grid to a datasource clientside without knowing my dataType the above question is born.

Thanks to all for the time.

Comment: Why would you ever not know the datatype? If anything, your request should dictate what type of data you *want* returned.

Comment: Example: My site just consumes data and displays/sorts it for the user. I get my data from webservices, that webservice might return xml or json. I don't really care which, I just need to display it. Just curious if it's possible.

Comment: What if you change your service to return the `content-type` along with the data. `{ contentType: 'json', data: [] }`

Comment: That would be nice if I had control over the service, but this assumes that I do not.

Comment: Make a "proxy" script on your server to do the fetching for you and give it back in exactly the format you want to display it in.

Comment: You can write a middle service that makes the call so that you can control the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is reasonable, but you are asking the user's browser to fetch information from a third party web server.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=coldplay`. No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://fiddle.jshell.net`' is therefore not allowed access.

Unless the third party grants you permission, the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will prevent your JavaScript from accessing any information about the response.

You should move your logic server side.

Comment: When I put the contenttype in the ajax call this is successfully consumed and I can display the results, so I'm not sure what you mean here. I also access this with fiddler?

Comment: @Malcoda — No. When you tell jQuery to use JSON-P, it makes a JSON-P request instead of an XHR request. JSON-P is not subject to the same origin policy (since it doesn't cause JS you wrote to access data from another server, but adds a script from the other server which calls your code (i.e. the reverse)). It only works if the server supports JSON-P (which is a means of granting permission as mentioned in the penultimate paragraph of this answer).

Comment: (And if it *does* support JSON-P, then the response will be encoded as JSON-P not JSON, XML or odata)

Comment: Ahhh... gotcha. So does this mean that a jquery request won't be able to access an xml or even json response? Is there an equivalent of jsonp for xml?

Comment: CORS is generic, it isn't tied to any data format. It doesn't do you any good if the server doesn't use it to give you permission though.

Comment: With this in mind, how is an ajax function able to access xml from a webservice?

Comment: Either the web service shares the same origin as the page hosting the script, or it returns the headers described in the CORS specification.